# Spatial Data on Python - "EEException: Can't encode object"

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, jupyter-notebook, geemap

I'm working on estimation chlorophyll-a using a Landsat 8 image on Python. But the result doesn't showing the image. I've tried to changing it but it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it. This is my script :

```
import ee
import geemap.folium as geemap
import numpy as np

Map = geemap.Map()

polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
    [121.731876,-2.330221], [121.069735, -2.317823], [121.214026,-2.994612], [121.785511,-2.992766]
])

studyarea= polygon

#Make a time
startYear = 2013
endYear = 2020

startdate=ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear,1,1)
enddate=ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear+1,12,31)
yearlist = range(startYear, endYear)
print(yearlist)

#Read the Data
for col in yearlist:
    col= ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")\
        .filterBounds(studyarea).filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', yearlist)).first()

#cloud masking area
def maskL8sr(col):
    # Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3)
    cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5)
    # Get the pixel QA band.
    qa = col.select('pixel_qa')
    # Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)\
            .And(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
    return col.divide(10000).divide(3.141593).updateMask(mask)

#Make a calculate for Clorophil-a
def chla (ynz) :
    image = col.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(ynz, ynz, 'year')).map(maskL8sr).mean()
    ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI')
    clh_a = image.expression(
        'exp(-0.9889*((RrsB4)/(RrsB5))+0.3619)',
        {'RrsB4': image.select('B4'),
         'RrsB5': image.select('B5')}).updateMask(ndwi)
    return clh_a.set('year', ynz).set('month', 1).set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(ynz,1,1)).set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(ynz,1,1)).map()                                         

parameter = {'min':0, 'max':1, 'palette':['blue','green']}
clhcollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([chla]).flatten()

Map.addLayer(clhcollection, parameter, 'Clorophyll-a')
Map.setControlVisibility(layerControl=True, fullscreenControl=True, latLngPopup=True)
Map
```

This the trouble that they say :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <module>
     45 parameter = {'min':0, 'max':1, 'palette':['blue','green']}
     46 clhcollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([chla]).flatten()
---> 48 Map.addLayer(clhcollection, parameter, 'Clorophyll-a')
     49 Map.setControlVisibility(layerControl=True, fullscreenControl=True, latLngPopup=True)
     50 Map

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\geemap\geemap.py:1401, in Map.add_ee_layer(self, ee_object, vis_params, name, shown, opacity)
   1398         print("The provided palette is invalid.")
   1399         raise Exception(e)
-> 1401 map_id_dict = ee.Image(image).getMapId(vis_params)
   1402 tile_layer = ipyleaflet.TileLayer(
   1403     url=map_id_dict["tile_fetcher"].url_format,
   1404     attribution="Google Earth Engine",
   (...)
   1408     max_zoom=24,
   1409 )
   1411 layer = self.find_layer(name=name)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\image.py:130, in Image.getMapId(self, vis_params)
    128 vis_image, request = self._apply_visualization(vis_params)
    129 request['image'] = vis_image
--> 130 response = data.getMapId(request)
    131 response['image'] = self
    132 return response

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\data.py:555, in getMapId(params)
    550 if 'version' in params:
    551   raise ee_exception.EEException(
    552       'Image version specification not supported.')
    553 request = {
    554     'expression':
--> 555         serializer.encode(params['image'], for_cloud_api=True),
    556     'fileFormat':
    557         _cloud_api_utils.convert_to_image_file_format(params.get('format')),
    558     'bandIds':
    559         _cloud_api_utils.convert_to_band_list(params.get('bands')),
    560 }
    561 # Only add visualizationOptions to the request if it's non-empty, as
    562 # specifying it affects server behaviour.
    563 visualizationOptions = _cloud_api_utils.convert_to_visualization_options(
    564     params)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:298, in encode(obj, is_compound, for_cloud_api, unbound_name)
    282 """Serialize an object to a JSON-compatible structure for API calls.
    283 
    284 Args:
   (...)
    294   A JSON-compatible structure representing the input.
    295 """
    296 serializer = Serializer(
    297     is_compound, for_cloud_api=for_cloud_api, unbound_name=unbound_name)
--> 298 return serializer._encode(obj)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:80, in Serializer._encode(self, obj)
     71 """Encodes a top level object to be executed server-side.
     72 
     73 Args:
   (...)
     77   An encoded object ready for JSON serialization.
     78 """
     79 if self._for_cloud_api:
---> 80   return self._encode_for_cloud_api(obj)
     81 value = self._encode_value(obj)
     82 if self._is_compound:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:98, in Serializer._encode_for_cloud_api(self, obj)
     96 def _encode_for_cloud_api(self, obj):
     97   """Encodes an object as an Expression or quasi-Expression."""
---> 98   value = self._encode_cloud_object(obj)
     99   if self._is_compound:
    100     # Wrap the scopes and final value into an Expression.
    101     value = _ExpressionOptimizer(value, self._scope).optimize()

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:221, in Serializer._encode_cloud_object(self, obj)
    209   result = {
    210       'functionInvocationValue': {
    211           'functionName': 'Date',
   (...)
    217       }
    218   }
    219 elif isinstance(obj, encodable.Encodable):
    220   # Some objects know how to encode themselves.
--> 221   result = obj.encode_cloud_value(self._encode_cloud_object)
    222 elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
    223   # Lists are encoded recursively.
    224   if self._is_compound:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\computedobject.py:152, in ComputedObject.encode_cloud_value(self, encoder)
    150   value = self.args[name]
    151   if value is not None:
--> 152     encoded_args[name] = {'valueReference': encoder(value)}
    153 invocation['arguments'] = encoded_args
    154 return {'functionInvocationValue': invocation}

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:221, in Serializer._encode_cloud_object(self, obj)
    209   result = {
    210       'functionInvocationValue': {
    211           'functionName': 'Date',
   (...)
    217       }
    218   }
    219 elif isinstance(obj, encodable.Encodable):
    220   # Some objects know how to encode themselves.
--> 221   result = obj.encode_cloud_value(self._encode_cloud_object)
    222 elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
    223   # Lists are encoded recursively.
    224   if self._is_compound:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\computedobject.py:152, in ComputedObject.encode_cloud_value(self, encoder)
    150   value = self.args[name]
    151   if value is not None:
--> 152     encoded_args[name] = {'valueReference': encoder(value)}
    153 invocation['arguments'] = encoded_args
    154 return {'functionInvocationValue': invocation}

    [... skipping similar frames: Serializer._encode_cloud_object at line 221 (4 times), ComputedObject.encode_cloud_value at line 152 (3 times)]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\computedobject.py:152, in ComputedObject.encode_cloud_value(self, encoder)
    150   value = self.args[name]
    151   if value is not None:
--> 152     encoded_args[name] = {'valueReference': encoder(value)}
    153 invocation['arguments'] = encoded_args
    154 return {'functionInvocationValue': invocation}

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:221, in Serializer._encode_cloud_object(self, obj)
    209   result = {
    210       'functionInvocationValue': {
    211           'functionName': 'Date',
   (...)
    217       }
    218   }
    219 elif isinstance(obj, encodable.Encodable):
    220   # Some objects know how to encode themselves.
--> 221   result = obj.encode_cloud_value(self._encode_cloud_object)
    222 elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
    223   # Lists are encoded recursively.
    224   if self._is_compound:

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\ee_list.py:69, in List.encode_cloud_value(self, opt_encoder)
     67 def encode_cloud_value(self, opt_encoder=None):
     68   if isinstance(self._list, (list, tuple)):
---> 69     return {'valueReference': opt_encoder(self._list)}
     70   else:
     71     return super(List, self).encode_cloud_value(opt_encoder)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:227, in Serializer._encode_cloud_object(self, obj)
    222 elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
    223   # Lists are encoded recursively.
    224   if self._is_compound:
    225     result = {
    226         'arrayValue': {
--> 227             'values': [{
    228                 'valueReference': self._encode_cloud_object(i)
    229             } for i in obj]
    230         }
    231     }
    232   else:
    233     result = {
    234         'arrayValue': {
    235             'values': [self._encode_cloud_object(i) for i in obj]
    236         }
    237     }

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:228, in <listcomp>(.0)
    222 elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple)):
    223   # Lists are encoded recursively.
    224   if self._is_compound:
    225     result = {
    226         'arrayValue': {
    227             'values': [{
--> 228                 'valueReference': self._encode_cloud_object(i)
    229             } for i in obj]
    230         }
    231     }
    232   else:
    233     result = {
    234         'arrayValue': {
    235             'values': [self._encode_cloud_object(i) for i in obj]
    236         }
    237     }

File ~\anaconda3\envs\gee\lib\site-packages\ee\serializer.py:265, in Serializer._encode_cloud_object(self, obj)
    256     result = {
    257         'dictionaryValue': {
    258             'values': {
   (...)
    262         }
    263     }
    264 else:
--> 265   raise ee_exception.EEException('Can\'t encode object: %s' % obj)
    267 if self._is_compound:
    268   # Save the new object and return a ValueRef.
    269   hashval = hashlib.md5(json.dumps(result).encode()).digest()

EEException: Can't encode object: <function chla at 0x00000260958B8040>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code. To begin with, the reason for your error is this:

```
clhcollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([chla]).flatten()
```

You're creating a list with `chla`, which is a function. `ee.ImageCollection.fromImages()` expects a list of `ee.Image` elements.

This is another piece of code probably not doing what you intended it to do:

```
for col in yearlist:
    col= ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")\
        .filterBounds(studyarea).filter(ee.Filter.eq('year', yearlist)).first()
```

In general, you should try to use more descriptive and precise variable names, it makes it easier for others (and your future self) to understand the code. For instance, in `def maskL8sr(col)`, `col` will actually be an image - that's a bit confusing.

I don't have folium installed, so I won't try the map rendering. But I do wonder if rendering an image collection to the map is really what you want. In any case, maybe something like this could do the calculations for you:

```
import ee
import numpy as np

ee.Initialize()

start_year = 2013
end_year = 2020
study_area = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
    [121.731876,-2.330221], [121.069735, -2.317823], [121.214026,-2.994612], [121.785511,-2.992766]
])

collection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR") \
    .filterBounds(study_area)

yearlist = range(start_year, end_year)


def mask_clouds(image):
    # Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    cloud_shadow_bit_mask = (1 << 3)
    clouds_bit_mask = (1 << 5)
    # Get the pixel QA band.
    qa = image.select('pixel_qa')
    # Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud_shadow_bit_mask).eq(0) \
        .And(qa.bitwiseAnd(clouds_bit_mask).eq(0))
    return image \
        .divide(10000) \
        .divide(3.141593) \
        .updateMask(mask)


def calculate_clorophil_a(year) :
    image = collection \
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year')) \
        .map(mask_clouds) \
        .mean()
    ndwi = image \
        .normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']) \
        .rename('NDWI')
    clorophil_a = image \
        .expression('exp(-0.9889*((RrsB4)/(RrsB5))+0.3619)', {
            'RrsB4': image.select('B4'),
            'RrsB5': image.select('B5')
        }) \
        .updateMask(ndwi)
    return clorophil_a \
        .set('year', year) \
        .set('month', 1) \
        .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(year,1,1)) \
        .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1))

clorophil_a_collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([
    calculate_clorophil_a(year)
    for year in yearlist
])
print(clorophil_a_collection.getInfo())
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! it's worked

Comment: @MartantiAjiPangestu_ kindly accept the answer, it will be helpful for others.